# (Javacard) How to know the reason of Error?

Tags: exception, rsa, javacard

I don't understand why the SW(6300) occurs. (objRSAKeyPair.genKeyPair();)

I'm implementing the RSA Sinature with 2048 bits of key size.
In case of 1024 bits, there's no problem.
But, in case of 2048 bits, the card outputs SW 6300.

Because I wanna know the exact reason, 
I implemented the Exception code below which output the detail reason.

```
    private RSAPrivateCrtKey    objRSAPriKey=null;
    private RSAPublicKey    objRSAPubKey=null;
    private KeyPair     objRSAKeyPair=null;
    private Signature       objRSASign=null;

    ...

public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength){
    new AAA(bArray, bOffset, bLength);
}

private AAA(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength){    

    // Create RSA Keys and Pair
    objRSAPriKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_CRT_PRIVATE, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048, false);
    objRSAPubKey = (RSAPublicKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC,  KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048, false);
    objRSAKeyPair= new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA_CRT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);        

    try {
        objRSAKeyPair.genKeyPair(); // [[[ Error Position ]]]
    }
    catch(CryptoException c)
    {    
        short reason = c.getReason();   
        ISOException.throwIt(reason);       
    }

    // Create Signature Object
    objRSASign = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_RSA_SHA_PKCS1, false);

    register();     
}
```

But the card still outputs 6300, not reason code.
Maybe JCRE outputs the error 6300.

I can't understand why JCRE outputs the SW 6300 which means "Authentication of host cryptogram failed" based on GPSpec.
The error code part is generating the keypair of RSA, not authentication.

< My Questions >

1. How to know the detail reason. (I'm not sure the Exception code
   part)
2. If the card does not support RSA 2048 bits, I expect that the
   card will output "0003" because of catch code part. But I can't
   understand the SW 6300.

Is there anyone to be my hero?
Thank you in advance.

---

I changed my code. (See below for my full code)
I followed your comments, so I moved the code part to the process().
But It still outputs SW 6300.
Please share your valuable knowledge and experience.

```
package Test;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacard.security.*;
import javacardx.crypto.*;

public class Test extends Applet{

private RSAPrivateCrtKey    objRSAPriKey=null;      // Object for RSA Private Key
private RSAPublicKey            objRSAPubKey=null;      // Object for RSA Public Key
private KeyPair                     objRSAKeyPair=null;     // Object for RSA Key Pair
private Signature               objRSASign=null;            // Object for RSA Signature

public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength){
    new Test(bArray, bOffset, bLength);
}

private Test(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength){   

    // Create RSA Keys and Pair
    objRSAPriKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_CRT_PRIVATE, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048, false);
    objRSAPubKey = (RSAPublicKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC,  KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048, false);
    objRSAKeyPair= new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA_CRT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);        

    objRSASign = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_RSA_SHA_PKCS1, false);

    register();
}

public void process(APDU apdu){
    byte buf[] = apdu.getBuffer();

    try {
        objRSAKeyPair.genKeyPair();     // [[[ Error Position ]]]
        ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9999);        // for check
    }
    catch(CryptoException c)
    {    
        //this line will give you the reason of problem 
        short reason = c.getReason();   
        ISOException.throwIt(reason);       // for check
    }
    finally 
    {
        ISOException.throwIt((short)0x8888);        // for check
    }

    return; 
}

}
```

---

This is APDU Command/Response

***1. (2048 bits) Applet Installation phase***

```
[ Connecting a Card in Terminal(ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 0) ]
- ATR(S) = 3B8E8001107880B0020031C0641F270100FF06
*** A Card is connected successfully

[ Mutual Authentication ]
[  Card  ] <==  00A4040008A000000003000000
[  Card  ] ==>  6F3D8408A000000003000000A5319F6E2A4790516882310258006B31444347311B6BC11142335811433358114433582A35000000000000000000009F6501FF9000
[  Card  ] <==  80500000082AF02FECBAED72B9
[  Card  ] ==>  000031444347311B6BC1FF020075CAA6408FCB3D6B964E5D3DD3F1E59000
[  Card  ] <==  8482000010A3C6E4CD3AD0D1636C8CC48696E0634C
[  Card  ] ==>  9000
[  Card  ] <==  80F28000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  08A000000003000000019E9000
[  Card  ] <==  80F24000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  07D410650990009007009000
[  Card  ] <==  80F22000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  07A0000000035350010008D410000004900300010008D410650990001000010008D410650990003000010008D41065099000900001009000
[ Package AID List ]
- A0000000035350
- D410000004900300
- D410650990001000
- D410650990003000
- D410650990009000
[ Applet AID List ]
- D4106509900090
*** Successful Mutual Authentication 

[ Delete Package ] - D410650990009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E400800A4F08D410650990009000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80F28000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  08A000000003000000019E9000
[  Card  ] <==  80F24000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  6A88
[  Card  ] <==  80F22000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  07A0000000035350010008D410000004900300010008D410650990001000010008D41065099000300001009000
[ Package AID List ]
- A0000000035350
- D410000004900300
- D410650990001000
- D410650990003000
[ Applet AID List ]
*** Package is deleted Successfully 

[ File Open ] 
- D:\Data\javacard\MobileOTP.cap
*** File is Opened and Parsed Successfully 

[ Load Cap ] - D:\Data\javacard\MobileOTP.cap
- Package AID : D410650990009000
- Applet AID : D4106509900090
- Instance AID : D4106509900090
[  Card  ] <==  80500000085EB7B1E16359F9C4
[  Card  ] ==>  000031444347311B6BC1FF020076711B2F5F02B4B725430BA4ECD63C9000
[  Card  ] <==  8482000010BECAD21E1061B522A3EFF4B4220814CC
[  Card  ] ==>  9000
[  Card  ] <==  80E602000D08D41065099000900000000000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E8000019C48201B2010012DECAFFED010204000108D410650990009000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800012202001F0012001F000B0015004E000C00C0000A00220000009E000000000000020100
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800021804001502020107A0000000620101020107A0000000620102
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800030E03000B0107D41065099000900021
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800040F06000C008003040004070100000080
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E80005C30700C0040087000B009A000E0087800B00AE0000009A800C00AE000000AE800200AE000005308F00043D181D1E8C00063B7A0540188C000518018700180187011801870218018703181006110800038D00079400000887001807110800038D0007940000098701188F000A3D051108008C000B870218100A038D000C8703188B000D7A0124198B000F2DAD028B00101199998D00111188888D001170212E1B8B0012290416048D00111188888D0011700D28051188888D00111505931177778D00117A
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800060D08000A00000000000000000000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800075105004E00130200000002000001020000020200000301000000068003000600002F06810D000181070001810900018110000681100006810F000380030101810C0003800A01038110010680070103810C01
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E8800825090022000938040404100F0E090E0015071D07081A040B0406080906070606060707060A09
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80F28000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  08A000000003000000019E9000
[  Card  ] <==  80F24000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  6A88
[  Card  ] <==  80F22000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  07A0000000035350010008D410000004900300010008D410650990001000010008D410650990003000010008D41065099000900001009000
[ Package AID List ]
- A0000000035350
- D410000004900300
- D410650990001000
- D410650990003000
- D410650990009000
[ Applet AID List ]
*** Cap File is Loaded Successfully 

[ Load Cap ] - D:\Data\javacard\MobileOTP.cap
[  Card  ] <==  80E60C001F08D41065099000900007D410650990009007D4106509900090010002C90000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
```

***2. (2048 bits) Select File command/response***

```
[ Connecting a Card in Terminal(ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 0) ]
- ATR(S) = 3B8E8001107880B0020031C0641F270100FF06
*** A Card is connected successfully

[  Card  ] <==  00A4040007D4106509900090
[  Card  ] ==>  6300
```

***3. (1024 bits) Applet Installation phase***

```
[ Connecting a Card in Terminal(ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 0) ]
- ATR(S) = 3B8E8001107880B0020031C0641F270100FF06
*** A Card is connected successfully

[ Mutual Authentication ]
[  Card  ] <==  00A4040008A000000003000000
[  Card  ] ==>  6F3D8408A000000003000000A5319F6E2A4790516882310258006B31444347311B6BC11142335811433358114433582A35000000000000000000009F6501FF9000
[  Card  ] <==  8050000008751EA7EA3CEA231D
[  Card  ] ==>  000031444347311B6BC1FF020073A2DF15969C21B0FE25E1397D60969000
[  Card  ] <==  8482000010C42CD2687C233DF4758159521D136FBE
[  Card  ] ==>  9000
[  Card  ] <==  80F28000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  08A000000003000000019E9000
[  Card  ] <==  80F24000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  07D410650990009007009000
[  Card  ] <==  80F22000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  07A0000000035350010008D410000004900300010008D410650990001000010008D410650990003000010008D41065099000900001009000
[ Package AID List ]
- A0000000035350
- D410000004900300
- D410650990001000
- D410650990003000
- D410650990009000
[ Applet AID List ]
- D4106509900090
*** Successful Mutual Authentication 

[ Delete Package ] - D410650990009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E400800A4F08D410650990009000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80F28000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  08A000000003000000019E9000
[  Card  ] <==  80F24000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  6A88
[  Card  ] <==  80F22000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  07A0000000035350010008D410000004900300010008D410650990001000010008D41065099000300001009000
[ Package AID List ]
- A0000000035350
- D410000004900300
- D410650990001000
- D410650990003000
[ Applet AID List ]
*** Package is deleted Successfully 

[ File Open ] 
- D:\Data\javacard\MobileOTP.cap
*** File is Opened and Parsed Successfully 

[ Load Cap ] - D:\Data\javacard\MobileOTP.cap
- Package AID : D410650990009000
- Applet AID : D4106509900090
- Instance AID : D4106509900090
[  Card  ] <==  805000000804800FCB0DD217FD
[  Card  ] ==>  000031444347311B6BC1FF020074009D775BA6E7CDC4AC1062CB20DC9000
[  Card  ] <==  8482000010EF96094F97DD5D4C163DF64AF2E04C7A
[  Card  ] ==>  9000
[  Card  ] <==  80E602000D08D41065099000900000000000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E8000019C48201B2010012DECAFFED010204000108D410650990009000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800012202001F0012001F000B0015004E000C00C0000A00220000009E000000000000020100
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800021804001502020107A0000000620101020107A0000000620102
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800030E03000B0107D41065099000900021
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800040F06000C008003040004070100000080
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E80005C30700C0040087000B009A000E0087800B00AE0000009A800C00AE000000AE800200AE000005308F00043D181D1E8C00063B7A0540188C000518018700180187011801870218018703181006110400038D00079400000887001807110400038D0007940000098701188F000A3D051104008C000B870218100A038D000C8703188B000D7A0124198B000F2DAD028B00101199998D00111188888D001170212E1B8B0012290416048D00111188888D0011700D28051188888D00111505931177778D00117A
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800060D08000A00000000000000000000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E800075105004E00130200000002000001020000020200000301000000068003000600002F06810D000181070001810900018110000681100006810F000380030101810C0003800A01038110010680070103810C01
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80E8800825090022000938040404100F0E090E0015071D07081A040B0406080906070606060707060A09
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
[  Card  ] <==  80F28000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  08A000000003000000019E9000
[  Card  ] <==  80F24000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  6A88
[  Card  ] <==  80F22000024F00
[  Card  ] ==>  07A0000000035350010008D410000004900300010008D410650990001000010008D410650990003000010008D41065099000900001009000
[ Package AID List ]
- A0000000035350
- D410000004900300
- D410650990001000
- D410650990003000
- D410650990009000
[ Applet AID List ]
*** Cap File is Loaded Successfully 

[ Load Cap ] - D:\Data\javacard\MobileOTP.cap
[  Card  ] <==  80E60C001F08D41065099000900007D410650990009007D4106509900090010002C90000
[  Card  ] ==>  009000
```

***4. (1024 bits) Select File command/response***

```
[ Connecting a Card in Terminal(ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 0) ]
- ATR(S) = 3B8E8001107880B0020031C0641F270100FF06
*** A Card is connected successfully

[  Card  ] <==  00A4040007D4106509900090
[  Card  ] ==>  8888                        // finally() { ... }
```

---

***1. Case 1***

SW : 8888

```
public void process(APDU apdu){
    byte buf[] = apdu.getBuffer();

  try {

      // Case 1
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6300);      // for check
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x5555);      // for check
      objRSAKeyPair.genKeyPair();

      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9999);      // for check
  }
  catch(CryptoException c)
  {    
      //this line will give you the reason of problem 
      short reason = c.getReason();   
      ISOException.throwIt(reason);     // for check
  }
  catch(ISOException c)
  {    
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6666);      // for check
  }
  finally 
  {
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x8888);      // for check
  }
  ISOException.throwIt((short)0x7777);      // for check

  return;   
}
```

***2. Case 2***

SW : 8888

```
public void process(APDU apdu){
    byte buf[] = apdu.getBuffer();

  try {

      // Case 2
      //ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6300);        // for check
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x5555);      // for check
      objRSAKeyPair.genKeyPair();


      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9999);      // for check
  }
  catch(CryptoException c)
  {    
      //this line will give you the reason of problem 
      short reason = c.getReason();   
      ISOException.throwIt(reason);     // for check
  }
  catch(ISOException c)
  {    
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6666);      // for check
  }
  finally 
  {
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x8888);      // for check
  }
  ISOException.throwIt((short)0x7777);      // for check

  return;   
}
```

***3. Case 3***

SW : 6300

```
public void process(APDU apdu){
    byte buf[] = apdu.getBuffer();

  try {

      // Case 3
      //ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6300);        // for check
      //ISOException.throwIt((short)0x5555);        // for check
      objRSAKeyPair.genKeyPair();

      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9999);      // for check
  }
  catch(CryptoException c)
  {    
      //this line will give you the reason of problem 
      short reason = c.getReason();   
      ISOException.throwIt(reason);     // for check
  }
  catch(ISOException c)
  {    
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6666);      // for check
  }
  finally 
  {
      ISOException.throwIt((short)0x8888);      // for check
  }
  ISOException.throwIt((short)0x7777);      // for check

  return;   
}
```

Comment: Please move your code to the process(..) method and try selecting applet....then you will get the correct reason code.  Why it is not working in constructor may be OPEN is not allowing it to throw any exception before register()...but i am not sure.
  
Applet selection command 
00 A4 04 00 XX AID
XX- lenth of applet AID

Comment: Yep, normally `ISOException` status word is not returned by `install`. Good catch, @AnuragSharma.

Comment: In my case, it's same. I supplement my full code above.

Comment: @user2642459 i doubt 6300 status words are coming from External authentication failure while seeking access to install applet or card manager PIN verification is wrong.   
This means your applet is not installed yet.
To investigate more please share your logs as well.

Comment: @user2642459 Please refer me with @ in comments so that i got the notification to help you faster.Thanks :)

Comment: *When* does it return 6300 exactly? Could you show us the command/responses? I agree with Anurag again; this issue is probably not generated in the `process()` method.

Comment: @Anurag Sharma As you can see my full code, I just send one command after installation phase. (command) 00A40400xx AID (SW) 6300. That's all. Strangely, in the case of 1024bit, there's no problem. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @user2642459 as Owlstead & i said, to investigate more please share the command/response.
And according to ISO 6300 SW is "key verification failed".
First try to verify "card manager PIN" before sending select applet command.
As you said it is working fine with 1024bit can you please share command/response of both the cases?From the install to selecting applet.Thanks

Comment: @Anurag Sharma I supplement APDU command/response from installation phase to SelectFile command of 2048 bits and 1024 bits.

Comment: @user2642459 i have analyzed logs provided by you everything is looking fine with install and select.But that 6300 SW is definitely a bug in card.
Please find the Javacard simulator project run this project in Eclipse you will get the desired output....what i can conclude from this there is something wrong with card....try to contact your card vendor.  
Simulator project [link]https://www.transferbigfiles.com/ca6138b6-9e60-4bc4-8b2c-4a7bb726446b/Mk4xxg0U9Mg4J5i5rOQraQ2

Comment: @user2642459 Can you please give it a try to catch ISOException as well because your card is throwing 6300 which is ISO exception but this is wrong.and catching ISOException in genKeyPair() is also wrong because according to doc it does not throw this exception but give it a try...i am sure its a buggy card.

Comment: @Anurag Sharma & owlstead Thank you for your interest. I also agree that there is some problem in the card. As you said, I'll tell the card vendor about.

Comment: @Anurag Sharma I'm not sure that I exactly understand what you said secondly. I supplemented the code, catch(ISOException) { ... }, and divided 3 code cases in try{ ... } above. But it does not achieve the ISOException code part as you see SW. So, I concluded there is some problem in the card, too. Anyway, Thank you, again.

Comment: @user2642459 ya you did it correctly but that was something not a good idea(suggested by me).  
Anyways report this issue to card vendor.

Comment: @user2642459 , Would you please tell me what tools do you use to communicate with the card? please refer me with @ . And  did your problem solved? if yes, how? Thank you.

Comment: @Abraham I used the tool which I developed by myself. And I couldn't solve it. I think that the card don't support 2048-bit RSA or I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @user2642459 Can you share it please? :)